# Does the distribution of dice numbers per se matter?

Tags: dice

A friend once told me that even ignoring the size of the scoops, a "spindown" D20 (Where neighboring faces are numbered sequentially, for easy look-ups.) produces different odds than a normal D20, which has more varied neighboring faces. Is this true?

Comment: did he make an argument to support this contention?

Comment: This question appears to be about the physics of die throwing rather than about statistics or machine learning.

Comment: He only said it was better for neighboring faces to not be close in value, but didn't mention cheating.

Comment: @whuber Note the "per se" and "ignoring the scoops" part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory: **No**; each side of a perfect *n*-sided die has a 1 in *n* chance of appearing.

In the real world: **Yes**; die shapes are imperfect, often favoring opposing sides, hence the tradition of making sure opposing sides are equal on average. As explained in [this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/13408/2668). Having all high numbers on one side also makes it more easy to fake fair rolls, like merely spinning or skittering the die.